# H-Bridge Low Side Sense Resistor - Position of Resistor and Bulk Capacitance

Tags: h-bridge, shunt, current-sensing

My question regards the considerations required in determining the location of a current sense resistor on the low-side of an H-Bridge. I've presented two scenarios.

Details: The H-Bridge load is a fly-back transformer driving a high voltage piezoelectric transducer with random frequencies between 20 kHz to 80 kHz. The transducer is driven on 50% duty cycle of 100 ms of pulsed signal then off for 100 ms. The transducer presents a wide range of impedance and harmonic resonance characteristics that are determined by the frequency it's being driven. Much of the band between 20 kHz and 80 kHz presents high impedance and the current drawn can be as little as 0.5 A. At self resonance it can be as much as much as 10 A.

Bulk capacitance is 2000 uF.

VDD is 12-14 V.

Sense resistor is 0.15 ohm (Current throttling will kick in at 3 A creating a voltage differential above ground of 0.5 V)

[image]

The first scenario would be what I would rather do. It locates the current sense resistor after the termination of bulk capacitance. This would essentially isolate the H-bridge from the rest of the circuit and allow inductive currents to circulate back to the bulk capacitor bypassing the sense resistor. This method would provide a less noisy and more normalized current reading. It would also create up to a 0.5 V difference between the H-bridge and ground. I'm unsure of how this would affect catch diode placement and the gate driver ICs. Also, the gate drivers would be connected to true ground as well as the common nodes of the bridge and at times present a -0.5 V ground path. Unless the driver ground be placed into the same node above the sense resistor, but I'd then run into the same problem with the ground path of the micro-controller supplying the signal input to the gate drivers. Is this scenario feasible?

The second scenario has the bulk capacitance outside the sense resistor. Bulk capacitance would have to circulate back through the sense resistor. This option would provide a more "real-time" current reading, but would be extremely noisy and produce higher currents through the resistor. Also, the circuit is liable to present transient voltage spikes through the sense resistor that would make it difficult to determine actual current draw.

Are there other options for low side current resistor placement?

Comment: Relocate your current-sense resistor to a high-side one with a diff-amp or high-side current sense amp to reduce any noise issues you may encounter. Your application, current levels, and frequencies are going to make it a problem. 1.5V is developed with 10A through a 0.15 resistance. That's definitely going to cause your gate driver to malfunction as well as loads of noise. Scenario 2 is untennable as a result, but Scenario 1 is not much better.

Comment: In scenario one, the sense resistor will not see the higher currents but a gradual current rise as bulk cap voltage sags. Current will be throttled on the high-side to 3A which will be the most the sense resistor will see - 0.5 V. My concern is how that difference will affect the gate drivers and whether the low-side catch diodes will connect to ground or the node above. Also, the differential may be beneficial considering clamping high current negative voltage transients on driver pins is of concern. Having the bridge node 0.5 V above ground during this condition may be helpful.

Comment: The capacitor in scenario A will supply enormous currents if problems occur. That --- a delay ---- is not what you need, for protection.

Comment: If your load is a flyback transformer then you don't want to use a H bridge.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf Thanks for your comment. Larger momentary currents within the bridge is wanted so they must be permitted - the bulk cap is there to provide those currents instead of the supply. The rest of the circuit and supply is fuse protected at less than these peak currents. Controlling the "circuits" input/output current is what is needed so that the fuse does not blow (and for max-power output settings of the device). As Toor stated, one option is to sense high-side input, but this question regards low-side placement.

Comment: @Andyaka A center tapped push-pull configuration would be preferred, but the circuit is limited to what transformers are commercially available that meet current and frequency requirements. Custom wound transformers are just not in the budget. The bridge circuit tests and functions well and is relatively noise free on both sides of the transformer. Dead-time is programmatically tuned based on frequency to limit transients during transitions and prevent saturation at lower frequencies.

Comment: Using a H bridge (with two extra transistors) in order to use a commercial flyback transformer does not seem like a good budget idea compared to a centre-tapped transformer.

Comment: @Andyaka The price difference of having transformers custom manufactured well exceeds the cost of a couple of transistors.

Comment: [Premier magnetics](http://www.premiermag.com/html/product-family/power-magnetics.html) offer a few off-the-shelf dual primary transformers as do others.